# Странные данные в изменении репутации при отзыве голоса

Tags: дефект, поддержка, репутация

Смотрел, смотрел, и решил спросить, **что это**?

> **Бага** или **фича**?

Пару часов назад обратил внимание на то, что у меня есть изменение в репутации, кто то проголосовал за мой ответ(Выделено красным):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако изменений в репутации нет и уведомлений нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотрел в статистике там вот такие строчки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. вроде как кто то отозвал голос, а затем вернул обратно. В истории изменения вопроса видим такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотел понять, почему нет уведомлений в изменении репутации(даже если было -10 и +10), однако это изменение фигурирует в сводке в моем профиле, да еще и стоит выше изменения, которое произошло через 5 часов...

Кто может рассказать, что произошло и как это интерпретировать?

На всякий случай, [ссылка на вопроc](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1485436/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-js)

Comment: По моим наблюдениям тут уже давно  не сообщают об получаемых минусах (берегут наше душевное равновесие -))

Comment: @avp Да не в минусе дело, вопрос в отображении этих изменений. Почему где то оно есть, где то нет. И по времени не совпадает, то что произошло раньше, отображается, как произошло позже...

Comment: @avp [как бы не так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9uPm.png). Другое дело что отозванные принятые ответы и голоса "за" и вправду не отображаются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый раз за ответ голоса были отданы 11 января в день публикации:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это был голос "за" и галка принятия.

Через месяц (11 февраля) голос был отозван (рейтинг стал нулевым, уведомления об уменьшении репутации не происходит), далее голос "за" поставили опять:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отозвать голос аж через месяц после первичного голосования удалось потому что между этими событиями ответ был изменён (хотя это и случилось практически сразу, но всё же на 7 секунд позже голосования).

То, что во [временной шкале ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1485438/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) указан только текущий день (11 февраля) является особенностью отображения шкалы (указывается только последнее изменение конкретного голоса, т.е. голоса определенного пользователя). Если голосовать и отзывать свой голос (даже в разные дни) то записи об этом во временной шкале не будет вовсе.

Comment: А почему они в разных местах стоят в разном порядке? Это просто особенность отображения?

Comment: @SwaD а где в разном? вроде бы везде одинаково.

Comment: Не, в общей статистике(1й скрин), стоит +10 выше, а на странице репутации ниже(3й скрин). Вот и было интересно, как добавилось отмененное без уведомления да и в разном порядке отображения )

Comment: @SwaD там есть режимы отображения разные: время/сообщение. В режиме "время" всё в  хронологическом порядке. В режиме "сообщение" как-то иначе сортирует, акцент, видимо в первую очередь на группировке, а не на сортировке.